# sp_depends equivalent query in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

Is there any query that is equivalent to sp_depends in PosgreSQL

Please let me know if there is any query related to that.

My goal is to find the table that are associated with all stored procedure  in my database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what or where sp_depends is, but judging by the name, the system view [pg_depend](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-depend.html) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: hi buddy, thanks for your reply. sp_depends is used in SQL server (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189487.aspx)  .It displays information about database object dependencies, such as the views and procedures that depend on a table or view, and the tables. i need to know the equivalent thing in postgreSQL..

Comment: @Dipen: so my assumption was correct. That information is stored in the system view pg_depend. Search for it in the PostgreSQL mailing lists archive. There are some sample statements for pg_depend available there